# How to pass $_GET variable in PHP correctly?

Tags: php, get

Is it wrong way to pass $_GET variable in MVC design?

```
http://localhost/video?id=123
```

I started to learn MCV design pattern and some people were telling me, that I'm doing wrong. The correct way would be:

```
http://localhost/video/?id=123
```

They were saying its kinda of 'standard' for passing $_GET in MVC. The slash isnt needed only if you access file directly, like:

```
http://localhost/video.php?id=123
```

Comment: `http://localhost/video/?id=123` Ahh, So I have been learning nothing all this time.

Comment: What's the connection between those urls and MVC?

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari what do you mean by that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with MVC. MVC is just a way to organize your code.

The way you rewrite/route URLs to controllers is up to you. Both ways work, as long as the URL matches what you defined on your backend!

Answer (score 0):

When passing parameters that would bring up information from your DB or http server is ok to use GET.

When sending information to modify the state of anything, change data in your DB or on your http server you should always use POST